# Open source Custom Chatbot project

Tags: chat

I am looking for an open source chatbot project that can be self-hosted.

The project should provide UI such that it lets the user design the flow of questions and answers. It should also provide UI to mention API to get answers for the questions. The API can be client-specific such that it can bring answers to the questions.

For example, let's say we have 3 clients. Client_1 deals with Orders, Client_2 deals with Applications and Client_3 deals with Tickets.

Each have their own requirements for chatbot.

Our project should give UI to configure chat flow for each of them along with specifying API (developed by clients) for each questions so that we can get answers using those APIs. Let's say in our case, if Client_1 setups the chatbot and one of the question is to know order status. Now, in order to know the status, they should have an API which can bring the status for a particular order.

Thank you

Comment: Do you already have an existing "API to get answers for the questions"?